# Como realizar UPDATE com ORDER BY no sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, order-by, sql-update

Gostaria de realizar um update ordenando os resultados do mesmo, para isso queria rodar um update como esse:

```
UPDATE pessoa SET nome = 'Jose' 
WHERE sobrenome LIKE '%Betalla%'
ORDER BY nome
```

Porém quando tento executar esse update ocorre um erro de sintaxe incorreta perto do "ORDER".

Gostaria de realizar o order by para pegar o primeiro resultado da consulta ordenada.

Comment: Mas o `UPDATE` não retorna nada, como diabos tu quer usar o `ORDER BY`? o.0

Comment: Um dos motivos é update não retorna registros, pode até retornar o número de linhas afetadas que é algo totalmente diferente ;)

Comment: Você pode fazer um select com essa consulta após o update ou gerar N updates com um select assim pode pegar o id de todas as linhas que serão alteradas.

Comment: Eu queria ordenar a ordem em que será realizado o update, teria como realizar isso?

Comment: O Update não irá retornar registros. O que poderia ser é um [tag:insert] com o [tag:select] já ordenado.

Comment: @William Por quê? Não faz sentido tu precisar ordenar como que vai acontecer o comando. No fim o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: @EduardoMendes no caso acho que eu preciso de um update, então um update com select já ordenado resolveria?

Comment: Acho que o mais próximo seria, algo como `SELECT +'UPDATE .... WHERE sobrenome like \'%abc\'+ id FROM tabela ORDER BY algo`

Comment: @DH. tem um caso aqui que essa ordenação alteraria o resultado final, por isso.

Comment: @William Única situação que consigo imaginar isso é tentar atualizar uma Primary Key sendo que a tabela aponta pra ela mesma, mas existe um bom motivo pra existir constraint que impede do valor de uma PK mudar

Comment: @William, eu vi uma solução para update com select, dá uma olhada neste [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query) e veja se lhe ajuda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para utilizar ORDER BY no update, é necessário utilizar uma subquery e ordená-la com a cláusula OVER, por exemplo:

```
;WITH pessoaAux AS(
  SELECT Id, Nome, Idade, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by nome asc) rowNumber
  FROM pessoa 
)
UPDATE pessoa SET Ordem = rowNumber
FROM pessoa p
INNER JOIN pessoaAux pAux on p.Id = pAux.Id
```

Também é possível realizar o ORDER BY na subquery, mas é necessário possuir a cláusula TOP, OFFSET ou FOR XML, como no exemplo:

```
;WITH pessoaAux AS(
  SELECT TOP 10 Id, Nome, Idade
  FROM pessoa 
  ORDER BY Nome
)
UPDATE pessoa SET nome = 'novo valor do nome'
FROM pessoa p
INNER JOIN pessoaAux pAux on p.Id = pAux.Id
```

Answer (score 4):

Baseado no seu comentário William você pode sim forçar um update baseado numa query ordenada, mas para isso você precisará utilizar de um cursor.

O curosr tornará seu update mais lento.

Seu script ficará mais ou menos assim

```
declare @id nvarchar(4000)
declare pap_log cursor read_only forward_only for 


select id from  pessoa 
WHERE sobrenome LIKE '%Betalla%'
ORDER BY nome

open pap_log
fetch next from pap_log into @id
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 

UPDATE pessoa SET nome = 'Jose' 
WHERE id =@id

fetch next from pap_log into @id
end
close pap_log
deallocate pap_log
```

Qualquer coisa pergunta ai

Answer (score -1):

```
UPDATE com ORDER BY
```

Quanto à questão levantada no título: Não há `ORDER BY` em um `SQL UPDATE comando`. `Postgres` atualiza linhas em ordem arbitrária. Mas você tem opções (limitado) para decidir se as restrições são verificadas após cada linha, após cada declaração ou no final da transação. Você pode evitar violações de chave duplicados para estados intermediários com `DEFERRABLE` restrição.

[Veja aqui mais detalhes.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735950/update-with-order-by)